# Troubleshooting electric pump that triggers GFCI

Tags: gfci, pump

I have a submersible pool cover pump that keeps triggering the GFCI outlet.  I know the pump is the problem because I have another, identical pump that does not trigger the outlet.  I'd like to try to repair the pump. I assume there's a short in it somewhere but how do I find it? Can anyone make suggestions for troubleshooting steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about a short.  It's about insulation leakage.  Tear it down and look for any place where electricity is able to contact where it should not, or places where debris is able to form a conductive path where it should not.   You can paint it with insulating paint, or epoxy.

Answer (score 0):

Had that problem with a hot tub.  Little caterpillars(?) were attracted to the heat perhaps?, and bridged the insulation gap between the heater and grounded sleeve, resulting in a current path to ground.  This is exactly the situation that GFCIs are designed to detect and trip for, because of the likelihood that a human is part of the current path to ground.
Start disconnecting things until the issue goes away, then investigate.  An ohmmeter might be helpful, along with a bright light.